# how to change array structure in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

Hello everyone i get some problem when try learn php with laravel,
there is the problem ...

i have an array structure like this :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 16
  1 => 19
  2 => 15
]
```

how can u change the array structure to look like this :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 16
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 19
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 15
  ]
]
```

im newb ,can somebody help me, im using laravel 5.8 ,very grateful if someone helps. sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it !

use array_chunck()

```
$convert = array_chunk($data, 1);

dd($convert);
```

output:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 16
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 19
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 15
  ]
]
```